# Android Emulator Development

Tags: windows-vista

We are new to android and trying to develop a emulator…
Can I have any information about how to start uo to develop an emulator.
We were trying to search for some resources online but couldn’t find any for emulator development
Online stuff is all related to application development…Please suggest us some tutorials which would help us.

Answer (score 0):

since the android environment is all open source, it would seem that the emulator should be also.  find the people who do that dev and you've found your answers.